# Repeating a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

Suppose I have a `10 x 10` matrix. I want to randomly choose 2 numbers from each column and take the square of the difference of these numbers. I wrote the R code for that and I get 10 values, but I wish to repeat this, say, 100 times, in which case I need to get 100*10=1000 numbers. How could I do that?

```
x <- rnorm(100)
m <- 10 
n <- 10 
X <- matrix(x,m,n) 

for (i in 1:m ) {
y <- sample(X[,i],2,rep=F)
q2[i] <- (y[1]-y[2])^2  
}
```

Comment: look at `?replicate`

Comment: Just wrap your `for` loop as a function and use `replicate` as @Davide Passaretti suggested

Comment: Probably just `replicate(100, sapply(data.frame(X), function(y) diff(sample(y, 2))^2))` will work

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks. It perfectly works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or as @Davide Passaretti and @nrussell mentioned in the comments, you can use `replicate`

```
f1 <- function(x, m){
 q2 <- vector(mode='numeric', length= m)
 for(i in 1:m){
 y <- sample(x[,i], 2, rep=FALSE)
 q2[i] <- (y[1]-y[2])^2
 }
q2
}

n <- 100 
res <- replicate(100, f1(X, m))
prod(dim(res))
#[1] 1000
```